# change devicePixelRatio in firefox on windows

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, browser

Default `window.devicePixelRatio` in `MS Windows` version of `Firefox` is not `1.0` so everything is rendered bigger there.
This property is read-only!

Is there a way to change this value to `1.0` in Firefox from the webpage (CSS, Javascript, Meta, Comments, ... )?

Thanks

Comment: "from the webpage", I don't think so. Only option : change your monitor ? Ps: I can't reproduce this on my computer.

Comment: @Kaiido: please check [this page](http://tombigel.github.io/detect-zoom/) in the `Live Example` section and if you be in Windows version of FF the nuimber is not `1.0`; I tested it on lots of monitors and versions of windows.

Comment: ... actually I'm trying from a VM and still can't repro... Will wait for other testers. The only way I can think of would be to overwrite this property with [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) method, but that would make the check to it irrelevant. There must be something that makes it behave like that. If you are absolutely certain there is a bug, then raise a bug report to Mozilla's Bugzilla.